# Error passing array as props to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am selecting some images by the picker and passing them through a props.

```
  const [ImageSource, setImageSource] = useState([]);
  const [ImageSourceviewarray, setImageSourceviewarray] = useState([]);

  addImages = ()=>{
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 200,
      height: 200, compressImageMaxHeight: 400,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 400, cropping: true, multiple: true
    }).then(response => {
      let tempArray = []
      setImageSource(response)
      response.forEach((item) => {
        let image = item.path
        tempArray.push(image)
        setImageSourceviewarray(tempArray)
      })
    })
  }

return(
    <PhotosPage images = {[...ImageSourceviewarray]}/>
);
```

Now I need to take these images and use them in my PhotosPage component.

```
export default ({images})=>{
  return(
    <>
        <CardItem style={styles.moldura}>
          <CardItem style={styles.itemCard}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{uri:images[0]}}
              style={styles.cardImageMenor}
            >
            </ImageBackground>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{uri:images[1]}}
              style={styles.cardImageMenor}
            />
          </CardItem>
        </CardItem>
      </>
  );
}
```

However, it is not working. Only the Images [0] that is appearing the image.

Comment: Does the following work? `.then(response => {
  setImageSource(response);
  setImageSourceviewarray(response.map(({ path }) => path));
})`

Comment: where do i put it?

Comment: Look in your posted code for `.then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is, the images array. For example, if `ImagePicker` response is an array of two images, here:

```js
response.forEach((item) => {
        let image = item.path
        tempArray.push(image)
        setImageSourceviewarray(tempArray) <--
      })
```

when you set ImageSourceviewarray for the second image, the view will not update, because you set it with the same object (tempArray address in not changed).
You can try this:

```js
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 200,
      height: 200, compressImageMaxHeight: 400,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 400, cropping: true, multiple: true
    }).then(response => {
      setImageSource(response);
      const newImageSourceArray = response.map(item => item.path);
      setImageSourceviewarray(newImageSourceArray);
    })
```